# Error code is 91 on Find

Tags: vba, excel

This may seem like a simple question but Im very new to VBA and Im not sure why I'm receiving the error.

```
Dim c As String
c = Sheet2.Range("B3:B54").Find("NLwk01")
```

> Error code is 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

I thought I should've maybe used cells instead of range, but that gives another error with

> Error code 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: `find` returns a range object I think... so you need to declare `c` as a range. and do `set c=`.

Comment: Absolutely correct, [it returns a range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) so you have a mismatch.

Comment: Your code will work if **NLwk01** actually exists within B3:B54. If that is the case then **NLwk01** is assigned to **c** since the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) is the defult property of a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). If it cannot be found (and you are not using enough parameters to properly define the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)) then there is nothing to assign to **c** and you receive the Error 91.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. *VBA Excel* is apparent from your tags, and the fact you have a problem you can't solve is apparent because you're posting here. Removing all of that from your title, it leaves *Simple error*, which is not a title that has any meaningful content. Your title should describe the actual problem or question in a way that is useful to future readers here who find it in a search result. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeeped that's good to know!

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The problem was indeed the range, but that was not the only problem. 
I know have: 
`Dim c <br>
Set c = Sheet2.Range("B3:B54").Find("NLwk01")`

This code however still does not return anything, even though cell B3 of Sheet2 contains a formula that gives NLwk01 as result. Note that not returning anything does not cause an error however.

I also tried it with a hard copy of the value, but that was not the problem. Anyone know what could still be causing the function to not find the value?

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in comment thread, Excel VBA `Find()` function returns the `Range` object. Therefore, pertinent to you particular example, it could be coded as in the following sample snippet:

```
Sub FindRowIndex()
    Dim c
    Dim rowIdx As Integer
    Dim cellValue As String

    'return Range object if found
    Set c = Sheet2.Range("B3:B54").Find("NLwk01")

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        'return the row index (shown as an example)
        rowIdx = c.Row
        'return the same string used as search criterion "NLwk01"
        cellValue = c.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Pertinent to your case search area (`"B3:B54"`) the `rowIdx` can be declared As `Integer`; for extended area you may use `Long`.

Also, as mentioned in comments thread, you may declare: `Dim c As Range`.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Why not declare **rowIdx** as a **Long** and **c** as a **Range**?

Comment: I think OP wants to store the value of cell into variable, not the location of cell.

Comment: @Jeeped: for coding simplicity c is declared as a variant, but, agree, it could be declared as Range. Best regards,